# Is there a name for 'map'ping multiple lists?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to map multiple lists in the same pass. Is there a name for this pattern?

Essentially, I'm looking for the name of something essentially similar to this:

`mapMultiple :: (([a,b]) -> c) -> [[a],[b]] -> [c]`

But hopefully can have more than two lists (my haskell is rusty and I'm not sure of how to write that type signature)

For something more concrete, let's say I have lists `A` and `B` such that:

`A = [1, 2, 3, 4] and B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

I want to be able to map a list of A and B like so:

`mapMultiple(([num, letter]) => ([ num, letter ]), [A, B]) == [[1,'A'], [2,'B'],[3,'C'],[4,'D']]`

In rough psuedo code, here is how you would implement it:

```
mapMultiple = (fn, lists) => map(fn, zip(lists))
```

I'm looking for the common name for this pattern/function.

Bonus points if you know its implementation name (or if it's not implemented) in Ramda.js

Comment: Definitely `zipWith`. As a method: `let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4], ys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']; xs.map((x, i) => [x, ys[i]])` or as a curried function: `const zipWith = ys => xs => xs.map((x, i) => [x, ys[i]]); zipWith(ys)(xs);`. I haven't a ramda solution though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `zipWith`, which is zip+map in Haskell:

```
> zipWith (*) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[4,10,18]
```

It is [available in Rambda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith), too.

Or `zipList3` for 3 lists:

```
> zipWith3 (\a b c -> a+2*b+3*c) [1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9]
[30,36,42]
```

The `ZipList` applicative generalizes to an arbitrary (statically known) number of lists, at the price of more verbosity:

```
> (\a b c d -> a+2*b+3*c+4*d) <$> ZipList [1,2,3] <*> ZipList [4,5,6] <*> ZipList [7,8,9] <*> ZipList [10,11,12]
ZipList {getZipList = [70,80,90]}
```

Answer (score 4):

`mapMultiple :: (([a,b]) -> c) -> [[a],[b]] -> [c]`

In Haskell, `[] :: * -> *` i.e. it takes a type and returns a type. Therefore, `[] [a] [b]` i.e. `[[a],[b]]` does not make sense.

You possibly meant to use a 2-tuple.

`mapMultiple :: ((a, b) -> c) -> ([a], [b]) -> [c]`

In that case, look at `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`. What you may be looking for is `map f . uncurry zip`.